# Upgrading from 1.1.1.RELEASE to 1.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

In upgrading from SCDF 1.1.1.RELEASE to 1.2.4.RELEASE, are there any database schema changes that I would need to be concerned about?

Specifically, if I'm already running SCDF 1.1.1.RELEASE on a Pivotal Cloudfoundry platform, and using a MySQL service tile as the underlying database, will the stream, app, and task metadata that is already in the database translate readily to SCDF upgraded to 1.2.4.RELEASE?

What other potential concerns might I need to take a close look at as I plan to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as documented on the official docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms

Comment: "Yes" to what?  I asked three questions above, all related to the same general topic.  Thanks for the link to the documentation, I did look, and there is a single "alter table" statement here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/cloud/task/migration/1.2.x/migration-mysql.sql

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the migration-script, there shouldn't be any other concerns wrt upgrade. At least in 1.1 -> 1.2, there's simply a case-conversion of a Task table name, which shouldn't impact existing records or any other functionalities.

That said, 1.2.4 is an old release. Please consider switching over to 1.3 GA release at the earliest. This release includes migration scripts as well, but again, we make sure to not introduce breaking changes in the minor releases (e.g., 1.2 -> 1.3), so switching to 1.3 should be straightforward.

Here's a [roundup of all the new features](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-3-continuous-delivery-usability-improvements-and-function-runner) available in the latest 1.3 release.